# How to make a cache exist for the duration of an indexing operation

Tags: content-search, indexing, computed-field

Is there a way to create a Sitecore custom cache which exists for the duration of an indexing operation.
I would like to store frequently looked up relationships which can be re-used by different computed index field classes to avoid performing the same lookups multiple times. After indexing completes, this cache can be cleared.

Comment: The question could be generalised to be "is there a way to serve data from a cache while it is being rebuilt". Seems like a .NET caching library solution would be good for this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't think anything general .NET is needed, but I might be missing your point? Sitecore has its own caching APIs which can be extended, my problem is about having some sort of "indexing context" onto which I can persist certain lookup objects. I could use the Sitecore cache for that, but not sure how I would clear it at the end of the indexing job.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. How about just use a memory cache? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Yeah that would work also, but my problem is how to clear this memory cache after the indexing job has finished?

Comment: Perhaps hook into the indexing:end event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible:

- `Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate` will raise `indexing:start` and `indexing:end` with index name that is being worked on.

The handler listening to start event could create a common cache using `BaseCacheManager.GetNamedInstance` with `registerNewInstance` parameter true (share the same cache instance by name solution wide).

- Wherever you need that cache during indexing, it could be recovered the same way.
- The second handler to deal with indexing, will free cache as soon as indexing ends.

Things to be aware of:

A) You might want to enable the logic for a few indexes only (add filter by name clause)

B) Use [Sitecore role-driven config](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/rule-based-configuration.html) to apply it only for the indexing instance

C) Your data is desired to implement `Sitecore.Caching.Interfaces.ISizeTrackable` to let Sitecore track memory consumption. Otherwise, it is [brute force calculation with little accuracy](https://making-it-faster.blog/2019/12/13/performance-crime-wrong-size-detection/).